# Set DIV width and height to 100% and do not resize it

Tags: css

I'm using 100% width and height so my website can fit properly a browser window.
The problem is that when I resize the window the website content also resizes.

I don't want the website content to resize, instead I want it to keep it sizes and add scroll bars.

I've tried this:

```
html,body{
   width:100%;
   min-width:100%;
}
```

And

```
html,body{
   min-width:100%;
}
```

No success at all, will I have to use javascript?

Comment: give it fixed width..

Comment: Try adding `max-width` as well. Can you post a JSFiddle of your current code?

Comment: @Druzion 100% is 100%.  To me it seens like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) what are you up to exactly?

Comment: @KAD, fixed width works, but I can't give it fixed width once many users have many different widths

Comment: @user4857867 Then I think your only option is to use Javascript

Comment: @KAD, thank you for your answer, I've saved the url, it will help me to make it responsive later.

Comment: You welcome dude, hope you get this sorted out

Comment: @KAD, may I ask you if you are experienced with responsive designs?

Comment: @KAD, could you start a chat with me if you still have your answer content? Thank you very much.

Comment: @user4857867 I have worked with lots of responsive sites, so I have a good idea about it, can someone guide us on how to start a chat here?

Comment: @KAD, I thought when you exchanged some messages in the comments, stackoverflow would suggest a chat. Testing.

Comment: I dont think private chat is allowed, in order to share the data as much as possible with others..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98168/discussion-between-user4857867-and-kad).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/retovi/edit?html,css,js,output

**convert the current element's 100% size to `px` size** using Javascript (jQuery)

```
// So the element is currently at 100% 100%
// CSS is done.
// Now jQuery will trigger...

var $el = $("#element");
$el.css({width: $el.width(), height: $el.height()});
```

Comment: What if the window is not maximized and then the user maximizes it?, isn't there a way to get the monitor resolution, not browser resolution?

Comment: This **answers your exact question** `"100% width and height but do not resize div on browser resize"`. Please edit your question to add more information of what you're actually up to.